# Apache Weblogic Post Field Limits

Tags: java, spring, apache, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a Java Spring web application running on Weblogic 12c and Apache 2.2 in front with a weblogic module. On two different pages in our application we have a form which has 54 input fields as per our requirements. In our server environment every time we submit this form, the Apache server redirects to the ErrorPage as a 302 and 304. When I reduce this to 50, it works and we get a 200 from Apache. I have tried removing different input fields as well and as long as it is 50 or under it works fine.

I tried directly hitting Weblogic and that does seem to work, which leads me to believe it's within Apache or the Apache Weblogic module.

I thought maybe it was this setting in Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfields

But this was not in any of our .conf files. I even confirmed by setting up a server-info via:

```
<Location /server-info>
    SetHandler server-info
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from 10.80
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Deny from 10.80.192.24
</Location>
```

It wasn't in the settings listed under /server-info/, but even when I added it as `LimitRequestFields 100`, it didn't seem to have any effect at either 100 or 0. It did appear in the server-info page after that, but I have a feeling it's not the setting I'm looking for anyway.

Does anyone know of a setting in Apache where this would come into play?

**UPDATE:** It seems it may actually be based on the length of the fields that are being submitted. When I remove two of the fields with longer names it seems to succeed.

**UPDATE 2:** It seems that it is exactly 2048 content-length that causes it to fail. Is the form being converted from POST to GET somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the Weblogic module for Apache has a feature that allows it to cache any POST greater than 2048 bytes. It also turns out that if you have the WLTempDir specified *and* that directory does not exist, this situation will occur.

Further reading: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/plugin_params.htm#sthref71